# Cannot specialize protocol type

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, swift5.7

Swift5.7 came with primary associated type. I try with these codes, But it shows up with error: Cannot specialize protocol type 'GenericDelegate'

```swift
class BaseResponse {}
class ConcreteResponse: BaseResponse {}

protocol GenericDelegate<Response>: AnyObject {
    associatedtype Response: BaseResponse
    func didGetResponse(response: Response)
}


class BaseCGI<T:BaseResponse> {
    weak var delegate: (any GenericDelegate<T>)? //error: Cannot specialize protocol type 'GenericDelegate'

    func didGetResponse(response: T) {
        self.delegate?.didGetResponse(response: response)
    }
}
```

How can we make an existential type with a specified associated type become a variable?

Use like this:

```swift
class FooDelegate: GenericDelegate {
    func didGetResponse(response: ConcreteResponse) {
        //do something
   }

}

let cgi = BaseCGI<ConcreteResponse>()
cgi.delegate = FooDelegate()
cgi.didGetResponse(response: ConcreteResponse())
```

Answer (score 1):

`GenericDelegate` has an associated type `Response` that must conform to `BaseResponse` and when you write:

```swift
weak var delegate: (any GenericDelegate<T>)?
```

it seems you want a `GenericDelegate` with `Response == T`.

The easiest way to do that is probably:

```swift
class BaseCGI<D: GenericDelegate> { 
    weak var delegate: D?

    func didGetResponse(response: D.Response) {
        self.delegate?.didGetResponse(response: response)
    }
}

let cgi = BaseCGI<FooDelegate>()
cgi.delegate = FooDelegate()
cgi.didGetResponse(response: ConcreteResponse())
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you must make your class `BaseCGI` generic over both the response type and the delegate type. Further you need to tell the compiler that the response type for the delegate is the same as the response type for the class

```
class BaseCGI<Response: BaseResponse, Delegate: GenericDelegate> where Delegate.Response == Response {
    weak var delegate: Delegate?

    func didGetResponse(response: Response)  {
        self.delegate?.didGetResponse(response: response)
    }
}
```

Then you create an instance like

```
let cgi = BaseCGI<ConcreteResponse, FooDelegate>()
```